# how to separate the logic from the form in java swing?

Tags: java, forms, swing, model-view-controller, logic

I have difficulties in  separating the logic of the game from the view. The view should be dumb and simply render the current state of the model. But I can not figure out how to do that. Could you please help me in making the code simpler and separating the logic from the form? Because I want to extend the game and add new things but I can not because of the confusing form of the code. I am new in java.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class ProjectileShooterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(600, 600);
        final ProjectileShooter projectileShooter = new ProjectileShooter();
        ProjectileShooterPanel projectileShooterPanel = new ProjectileShooterPanel(
                projectileShooter);
        projectileShooter.setPaintingComponent(projectileShooterPanel);
        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        controlPanel.add(new JLabel("Angle"));
        final JSlider angleSlider = new JSlider(0, 90, 45);
        controlPanel.add(angleSlider);
        controlPanel.add(new JLabel("Power"));
        final JSlider powerSlider = new JSlider(0, 100, 50);
        controlPanel.add(powerSlider);
        JButton shootButton = new JButton("Shoot");
        shootButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int angleDeg = angleSlider.getValue();
                int power = powerSlider.getValue();
                projectileShooter.setAngle(Math.toRadians(angleDeg));
                projectileShooter.setPower(power);
                projectileShooter.shoot();
            }
        });
        controlPanel.add(shootButton);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.getContentPane().add(projectileShooterPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class ProjectileShooter {
    private double angleRad = Math.toRadians(45);
    private double power = 50;
    private Projectile projectile;
    private JComponent paintingComponent;

    void setPaintingComponent(JComponent paintingComponent) {
        this.paintingComponent = paintingComponent;
    }

    void setAngle(double angleRad) {
        this.angleRad = angleRad;
    }

    void setPower(double power) {
        this.power = power;
    }

    void shoot() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                executeShot();
            }
        });
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
    }

    private void executeShot() {
        if (projectile != null) {
            return;
        }
        projectile = new Projectile();
        Point2D velocity = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angleRad).transform(
                new Point2D.Double(1, 0), null);
        velocity.setLocation(velocity.getX() * power * 0.5, velocity.getY() * power * 0.5);
        projectile.setVelocity(velocity);
        long prevTime = System.nanoTime();
        while (projectile.getPosition().getY() >= 0) {
            long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            double dt = 3 * (currentTime - prevTime) / 1e8;
            projectile.performTimeStep(dt);
            prevTime = currentTime;
            paintingComponent.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return;
            }
        }
        projectile = null;
        paintingComponent.repaint();
    }

    Projectile getProjectile() {
        return projectile;
    }
}

class Projectile {
    private final Point2D ACCELERATION = new Point2D.Double(0, -9.81 * 0.1);
    private final Point2D position = new Point2D.Double();
    private final Point2D velocity = new Point2D.Double();

    public Point2D getPosition() {
        return new Point2D.Double(position.getX(), position.getY());
    }

    public void setPosition(Point2D point) {
        position.setLocation(point);
    }

    public void setVelocity(Point2D point) {
        velocity.setLocation(point);
    }

    void performTimeStep(double dt) {
        scaleAddAssign(velocity, dt, ACCELERATION);
        scaleAddAssign(position, dt, velocity);
    }

    private static void scaleAddAssign(Point2D result, double factor, Point2D addend) {
        double x = result.getX() + factor * addend.getX();
        double y = result.getY() + factor * addend.getY();
        result.setLocation(x, y);
    }
}

class ProjectileShooterPanel extends JPanel {
    private final ProjectileShooter projectileShooter;

    public ProjectileShooterPanel(ProjectileShooter projectileShooter) {
        this.projectileShooter = projectileShooter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gr;
        Projectile projectile = projectileShooter.getProjectile();
        if (projectile != null) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            Point2D position = projectile.getPosition();
            int x = (int) position.getX();
            int y = getHeight() - (int) position.getY();
            Ellipse2D.Double gerd = new Ellipse2D.Double(x - 01, y - 10, 20, 20);
            g.draw(gerd);
            // g.fillOval(x-01, y-10, 20, 20);
        }
        Rectangle hadaf1 = new Rectangle(450, 450, 50, 50);
        Rectangle hadaf2 = new Rectangle(500, 450, 50, 50);
        Rectangle hadaf3 = new Rectangle(475, 400, 50, 50);
        g.draw(hadaf1);
        g.draw(hadaf2);
        g.draw(hadaf3);
    }
}
```

I will be so thankful.

Comment: Essentially, you're asking about [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). For each piece of code you need to be asking yourself what it is responsible for.  If it's responsible for managing the state of the game and making decisions about the state, then it should belong in the model, if it's about changing the state (maybe via the keyboard or mouse), then it should be in the controller, if it's responsible for painting the state, then it should be in the view.

Comment: You should be able to take one or more parts and replace it with a different implementation without needing to re-code the other sections.  It's also important to note, that sometimes, you need information about one part of the program which doesn't really belong (responsibility/management wise) in another, like the container's current size for example.  This is where a delegate can come in useful, it simply provides a key piece of information to another part of the program while maintaining the responsibility for it

Comment: You should also prefer interface over implementation, to further decouple your code

Comment: Can someone show how to do it please?